# How is Phantom a "top sniper" when they seem to spend little time actually acting as snipers?

Tags: requiem-for-the-phantom

On several occasions, Phantom's role in Inferno is described by Scythe Master. For example, in the beginning of ep. 11:

> Phantom… the strongest assassin in Inferno… the title given to the top sniper in the organization…

I can see how Ein and Zwei are the strongest assassins in Inferno, but I'm confused by the designation of "top sniper." To me, "top sniper" suggests that the person specializes and is especially proficient in, well, sniping. But Ein and Zwei spend a lot of time in the series (at least up to ep. 10) in close quarters combat or situations that lead to close quarters combat. It was probably intended that they fight in such situations, given that they follow certain instructions when carrying out orders. They also seem to have been specially trained for such situations, based on what I remember from ep. 2 and 3. The only instance that I recall where Phantom serves as a sniper outright is in ep. 7, where Ein is ordered to shoot people who are overseeing a narcotics shipment.

In contrast, other fictional snipers that I can recall, such as Riza Hawkeye from *Fullmetal Alchemist* and Sinon from *Sword Art Online*, clearly have a background in sniping, even if they end up in close quarters combat on numerous occasions.

How is then Phantom a "top sniper"? Or is there something I'm misunderstanding, either about the nature of Phantom's work, or about what snipers typically do?

Comment: Update: fwiw both Ein and Zwei are snipers in ep. 16.